# print x,y coordinates of selected pixel of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on a project in which I want to extract an outline of a given image.
I have two images; a foreground image and a background image.  I apply subtraction on these images and put a condition if the difference is not equal to zero.  Then I print that coordinate value.  here is my current code:

```
I=imread('starObject.jpg')

B=rgb2gray(I);
imshow(I);

A=imread('starB.jpg');
C=rgb2gray(A);
[columns rows]=size(C) 
Diff(i,j)=B(i,j)-C(i,j);
if (Diff(i,j)>0||Diff(i,j)<0)
    fprintf('1st difference');
    disp(Diff(i,j));
end 
end
end
imshow(Diff);
```

The above code print difference value of pixels.  I want coordinates. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your code above, `i` and `j` are already the pixel coordinates. For printing, you could use something like this

```
[rows, columns] = size(C); %# rows are first!!
for i = 1 : rows
    for j = 1 : columns
        if (Diff(i,j) ~= 0)
            sprintf('(%d, %d)', i, j);
        end
    end
end
```

for example.

Another approach would be to use the `find()` function, which might look like this

```
[r, c] = find(Diff ~= 0);
for idx = 1 : length(r)
    sprintf('(%d, %d)', r(idx), c(idx));
end
```

**By the way:** It is a **very, very** bad idea to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab because you normally use it for defining complex numbers. Don't be suprised, if

```
x = 10 + 20*j
```

does not work any more after your loops.

Comment: thanx but i cannot use mouse function because i need to do it automatic

Comment: @marry: Ok, I adapted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorize your code. Don't use for loops to iterate over coordinates, it's slow, ugly and not how the language is meant to be written. See if the following works for you.

```
A    = rgb2gray (imread ('starObject.jpg'));
B    = rgb2gray (imread ('starB.jpg'));
Diff = B - C;
inds = find (Diff);
sprintf ("Different at indexes: %i\n", inds);
```

If you want to print subscripts rather than liner indexes, use `ind2sub` to convert one into the other or find with two output arguments. For example:

```
[iRows, iCols] = find (Diff);
printf ("Different at coordinates (%i, %i)\n", [iRows'; iCols']);
```